# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g(\frac{k}{n})\frac{(\lambda n)^ke^{-\lambda n}}{k!} \overset{D}{\to}g(\lambda)$ if $g$ continuous.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Given a continuous function $g$ I am trying to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g(\frac{k}{n})\frac{(\lambda n)^ke^{-\lambda n}}{k!} \overset{D}{\to}g(\lambda)$.

I think the idea is probably to use the continuous mapping theorem. If we define $X_n \sim P(\lambda n)$, then the summation can be rewritten like $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g(\frac{k}{n})P(X_n = k)$. Now I would like to apply the continuous mapping theorem for $E[g(X_n)]$ somehow. However, $E[g(X_n)] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g(k)\frac{(\lambda n)^ke^{-\lambda n}}{k!}$ which is close but not exactly the same to the original term. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, the left hand side is $E(g(X_n/n))$ and your idea works if you want to show $g(X_n/n)\to g(\lambda)$ in distribution.

Comment: I see, but isn't $E(g(X_n/n)) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g(k/n)P(\frac{X_n}{n} = k)$? I don't see how $P(\frac{X_n}{n} = k) = \frac{(\lambda n)^k e^{-\lambda n}}{k!}.$ @StubbornAtom

Comment: @PeterSampodiras No, that formula.is wrong

Comment: What is the correct formula for $E(g(X_n/n))$ then?

Comment: You have $E\left[g\left(\frac{X_n}n\right)\right]=\sum_k g(\frac{k}{n})P(X_n=k)=\sum_k g(k)P\left(\frac{X_n}{n}=k\right)$. But what exactly is the question? That the sum converges to $g(\lambda)$? Why do you have a '$\stackrel{D}\to$' then?

Comment: Why is $\sum g(k)P(\frac{X_n}{n}=k) = \sum g(k/n)P(X_n=k)$ ? That is the step I am missing.

Comment: @PeterSampodiras $E(g(X_n / n)) = \sum_{k}g(k / n)P(X_n = k)$ by the Law of the Unconscious statistician